# how to insert mysql after post publish

Tags: php, wordpress

i created a custom table in my wp table called  `wp_publish` fields : `title`, `url`, `postdateword`
i want to insert `post` `data` when `post` is `published`

for sample
I publish a new post and the post contains `url`, `title`, `details`
`insert` 3 `field` on `wp_publish` automatic.

it is possible ? i am creating plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `save_post`, it is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_data' );
function save_data($post_id ){
  // check $post_id in table if not exists in table insert, 
}
```

please see this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: may i add this in my function.php ? i want fire event when post publish

Comment: no in your plugin core file or any file in your plugin if you are developing a plugin

Comment: yes working nice i tested code but i got 5 times entry of a post ? why ?

Comment: `add_action( 'save_post', 'save_data33' );
function save_data33()
{
 global $wpdb;
 $wpdb->insert( 'tablename', array( 'name' => "inserted_text"), array('%s'));
// $wpdb->print_error();
// $wpdb->hide_errors();
}`

Comment: the save_post hook will call whenever the post/page created or updated, may be you were updated 5 times, check before inserting. My answer is edited you can get the post id check with it

Comment: yes but if postid already in my table and i update the post ? how to update title ?

Comment: `$post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );`

Comment: $wpdb->update('table',  array(  'title' => $post_title ), 
 array( 'id' => $post_id  ), 
 array('%s'), 
 array( '%d' ) 
);

Answer (score 1):

You can try it works when new post publish

```
function authorNotification($post_id) 
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 'tablename', array( 'name' => "inserted_text"), array('%s'));
    $wpdb->print_error();
    $wpdb->hide_errors();
}
add_action('publish_post', 'authorNotification');
```

Comment: what if i update the post ? if postid already in my cutom table ?